# SharePoint 2010 Web Analytics Top Pages

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

Can someone explain what Top Page page view actually is? I'm looking at our web analytics and the page view count seems very low for a particular PDF file. If I look at the IIS logs and filter it to that PDF I am getting more hits in one day than SharePoint analytics is reporting for a month.

Is it a view per user? Is it due to cached content?

Comment: I should probably rephrase this question to ask if the top pages report is plain wrong. If I also look in the health and usage table in SQL, it also shows a much higher count

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, this is related to the 200/206 status codes that PDFs generate when viewed in the browser.

200 = OK

206 = Partial content

Consider a 10 page PDF. When viewed in a browser, the PDF will generate one hit with a 200 status code for the document, and ten hits with a 206 status code (one for each page).  But if the PDF is downloaded directly, there will only be one hit with a 200 status code.

Most analytics products count hits with 206 status codes as pageviews, because it's an easy correlation (i.e. three pages viewed = three pageviews).  If you just want to see how many times the PDF was accessed, just look at the count of 200 status codes for the PDF.